# How to identify all columns in Snowflake schema that has only null values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake client)

.........................

Needing to filter null data columns, I heard that the information about of all columns of all tables of a database can be found in view "COLUMNS" of schema `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

However, I found that doesn't show correct data with 100% accuracy. When we give constraint as not Null or it is primary key then it will show Non-nullable. And for other columns it show Nullable. But that's not right, we need to actually check the data in the column even if there is one record then that column is Non-nullable.

Is there another way to do this?

.........................

Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context?  For example, what is the query you are running against the information_schema view, and what are the expected results versus the actual results?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Gavin. It's pretty hard to tell what you are asking here, so you should consider rewording this question for clarity. Also, from the question it seems like you would benefit from a fundamental understanding of SQL. There are a number of good tutorials and books out there to get you started.  Here's a good intro with links to other resources and books: https://learntocodewith.me/posts/sql-guide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The views in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` are meant to describe the structure of the tables in a database, not their contents. You can trivially determine which columns *may* or *may not* contain `null` values by querying the `COLUMNS` view of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```sql
select COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE from YOUR_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC';
```

However, this won't tell you whether these columns actually ever contain null. In order to do this you actually need to run a query against the table you are interested in. Fortunately the `count` function implicitly counts only non-null values, so you can easily use this to determine what percentage of rows contain `null` values it the columns you are interested in. For example:

```sql
select count(1) as TOTAL, count(YOUR_COL) as YOUR_COL_NON_NULL
from YOUR_TABLE;
```

If your table has 100 rows and never has any nulls you would get back

```
+-------+-------------------+
+ TOTAL | YOUR_COL_NON_NULL |
+-------+-------------------+
| 100   | 100               |
+-------+-------------------+
```

However if your table had 100 rows and 25 of them contain `null` values in the column `YOUR_COL` you would get back:

```
+-------+-------------------+
+ TOTAL | YOUR_COL_NON_NULL |
+-------+-------------------+
| 100   | 75                |
+-------+-------------------+
```

None of this is specific to Snowflake, it is just basic SQL.